# Virtual keyboard on Top

Tags: c#, wpf, touch

We are going to create a virtual keyboard (on screen keyboard) with customized keys (no Ctrl, Alt and ...). 
The problem is when we set the application to be `Topmost="Ture"` then it is not possible to find the last active application's window to send the selected key to it. (The keyboard application is now the active one.)
We did a few search but couldn't find anything helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help and answers.
I find [Wosk](http://wosk.codeplex.com/) and it solved my problem.
You can review the code.

Answer (score 3):

Keep a handle to the last window before you set the prperty to true, take a look at [GetForegroundWindow()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [GetActiveWindow()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646292%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), then use a the [SetActiveWindow()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646311%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to set it back after done with your keyboard application.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Foreground {
  class GetForegroundWindowTest {

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling=true)]
    public static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

    public static void Main(string[] args){
        IntPtr fg = GetForegroundWindow(); //use to keep the last active window
        // set the topmost property to your keyboard        
        //Set fg to be active again when needed using SetActiveWindow()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: User may need to use the keyboard on various applications and we need to switch back to last active window after each key press on our keyword.

Comment: Sorry i didn't understand the problem, you keep the handle of window A when keyboard app is started then set it to topmost, and on a key click you set the saved handle to active again.

Comment: Target application may change based on user's desire.

Comment: you can keep get the last active window on each getFocus or Activated veent. see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activated.aspx